# Trying to create a deck of cards using For Loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a deck of cards using 2 arrays. One array is the suits and the other is the values. My thought was to use a for loop to iterate through an array to create the 52 cards deck. However, I can't seem to get the syntax right.

I tried using `forEach` method.

```js
var deck = [];
var suits = ["diamonds", "spades", "hearts", "clubs"];
var values = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"];

suits.forEach(function(suits) {
  deck.push(suits);
  deck.push(values);
});

console.log(deck)
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Basically to replicate a deck of cards. EX: Ace of Spades, King of Hearts, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two loops, one over the suits, and one over the face values, e.g.

```js
var deck = [];
var suits = ["diamonds", "spades", "hearts", "clubs"];
var values = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"];

suits.forEach(function(suit) {
  values.forEach(function(value) {
    deck.push(`${value} of ${suit}`);
  });
});

console.log(deck);
```

Alternatively, you can use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
var suits = ["diamonds", "spades", "hearts", "clubs"];
var values = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"];
var deck = suits.flatMap(suit => values.map(value => `${value} of ${suit}`));

console.log(deck);
```

Note: `flatMap` is not supported by some older browsers, so you may need  polyfill.

And just for demonstration purposes, you could also do this with [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#xprod)'s [`map`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#xprod) and [`xprod`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#xprod):

```js
var suits = ["diamonds", "spades", "hearts", "clubs"];
var values = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"];
var deck = R.map(([suit, value]) => `${value} of ${suit}`, R.xprod(suits, values));

console.log(deck);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
suits.forEach(s=> values.forEach(v=> deck.push(v+' of '+s)));
```

```js
var deck = [];
var suits = ["diamonds", "spades", "hearts", "clubs"];
var values = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"];

suits.forEach(s=> values.forEach(v=> deck.push(v+' of '+s)));

console.log(deck);
```

Comment: First, simplest and best solution. Would recommend to add first the code formatted (or "beautified") with a small description so the user can see and understand it clearly. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
var deck = new Array();
var suits = ["diamonds", "spades", "hearts", "clubs"];
var values = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"];


function makeDeck()
{

    for(var i = 0; i < suits.length; i++)
    {
        for(var x = 0; x < values.length; x++)
        {
            var card = {Value: values[x], Suit: suits[i]};
            deck.push(card);
        }
    }

    return deck;
}

makeDeck();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```js
var deck = [];
var suits = ["diamonds", "spades", "hearts", "clubs"];
var values = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"];

suits.forEach(function(suit) {
  values.forEach(function(value) {
    deck.push([suit, value]);
  });
});

console.log(deck)
```